# Can I edit access backend file while others are using it?

Tags: database, ms-access, backend

How much can I edit a backend file of an Access database while others are using it?  My understanding has been that you can't, but I wanted to confirm that before I commit to a lot of late nights.  And in regards to "how much can I edit it", I mean tasks such as adding fields to tables, deleting them, adding new tables etc.

Also, how does this compare to working with an SQL Server backend?

If it's not apparent, my database is split, and I currently have a low number of users (1-2) on it at a time.  I'm using Access 2007

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not edit a live back-end, however, you can make most, or possibly all, of your changes on an empty copy and just append the live data to the various tables with a little SQL and VBA.

Comment: Hmm. That's a good idea.  So is editing a live backend possible, but risks corruption or something like that?

Comment: It risks driving your users to violence as well, as you will lock up the db. I simply would not risk it.

Comment: I always assumed you need exclusive access to change the db schema.  So if my assumption is correct, you can not make your changes while others are using it.  However I'm uncertain whether that assumption is correct because "*I would not edit a live back-end*".

Comment: @HansUp If by exclusive access you mean that you must Open Exclusive, I have not found that to be the case. I find that you can change the schema of any tables that are not currently in use, but I have only tried in test cases, because messing with a live database just sounds too risky for me.

Comment: @Remou  OK, I see you're right.  Thanks.  I didn't realize that is possible mainly because I avoid changing the schema of a live back-end.  Considering it makes me cringe.  :-)

Comment: So it seems that we assume that it's unsafe but aren't completely sure - who's going to be the brave soul to try do it!  Probably best that no one does, I agree that it seems like very bad practice.

Comment: @andrewb I am not assuming, the test cases were fairly life like. You will lock files and that is unsafe.