# ALTER ms-access table that is locked

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, jet

I am trying to add a column to a table in an ms-access backend which is being used by multiple ms-access front-ends.  When I try to add a column to the table like so (or with DAO):

```
sql = "ALTER Table MyTable " & _
      "ADD COLUMN NewCol Integer "
CurrentDb.Execute (sql)
```

I get an error, and Access complains that the table is already locked by another user.

Is there a way to ALTER a locked table?

If you can't, how do you handle modifying a backend table that is always in use?  Just wait until everyone goes home for the weekend?  Are there some admin tricks that I can use to avoid this in the future?

Comment: It is not safe to work on a live backend.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891715/can-i-edit-access-backend-file-while-others-are-using-it/10894569#comment14209943_10894569

Comment: @Remou So basically: be safe, wait until no one is using the backend, and make the schema changes.